# How to read Spring Boot metric values?

Tags: spring-boot, metrics

I am using Spring Boot Metrics http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-metrics.html#production-ready-metrics to manage some domain-specific counters.

I have `@Autowired org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.CounterService` in my classes and I am increasing metrics on domain-specific events (various phases of parsing my request).

I would like to read those metrics in my test (to check if my test request went through all required stages ), but there is no get method on `CounterService`. I see that all implementations of `CounterService` have some `private ConcurrentMap` with metrics, but there is no (clean) way to get to this data structure.

I am using Spring Boot `1.3.5.RELEASE` .

edit: 
I am interested in integration test, and if possible I do not want to mock any components.

Currently I am using REST call against /metric endpoint and I parse returned json, but I do not like that approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be to use a mock `CounterService` and to then verify that the expected methods have been called on the mock.

If you'd prefer something that's more of an integration test then you can use a `MetricReader` to read in the metrics that `CounterService` has written. You should be able to `@Autowire` a `MetricReader` or `MetricRepository` (the latter is a combination of `MetricReader` and `MetricWriter`) and call `findOne`.

Comment: thanks, MetricRepository looks perfect! I saw Spring Boot documentation, but it describes another use cases- exporting metrics to Redis and other databases.

I think that MetricRepository solves another problem that I have- I would like to have HTTP endpoint (for internal or test use only) that would reset metrics. That will make testing easier. I currently read metrics in Jmeter tests (before and after generating traffic).